# Comparison test for convergence of Improper Integral

Tags: calculus

The comparison test works for improper integrals $\int_{a}^{\infty} f(x) \ dx$ where $a\geq 0$.

Supposedly i want to find the convergence of $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \ dx = \int_{-\infty}^{a} f(x) \ dx + \int_{a}^{\infty} f(x) \ dx$.

How do i apply comparison test for $\int_{-\infty}^{a} f(x) \ dx$?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $f(x)\geq 0$ in $(-\infty,a]$. If you find a function $g:(-\infty,a]\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $$0\leq f(x)\leq g(x)$$ whose improper integral is convergent
$$\int_{-\infty}^{a}g(x)dx<\infty$$
then
$$\int_{-\infty}^{a}f(x)dx\leq\int_{-\infty}^{a}g(x)dx<\infty$$

**Resuming**:  If $\ 0\leq f(x)\leq g(x)$, then

1) $\ \displaystyle{\int_{-\infty}^{a}f(x)dx=\infty \Longrightarrow \int_{-\infty}^{a}g(x)dx=\infty}$

2) $\ \displaystyle{\int_{-\infty}^{a}g(x)dx<\infty} \Longrightarrow \displaystyle{\int_{-\infty}^{a}f(x)dx<\infty}$